# Wordpress, consume 3rd party REST Api

Tags: wordpress, rest, api

We have Rest API implemented on .Net Core. This REST API has several endpoints that return JSON data

And now we need to extend one of our Wordpress sites to consume this API.

Basically what we need is to display JSON data (that comes from the REST API) on Wordpress pages.

I think the ideal scenario for us would be to implement templates pages on Wordpress and then just populate placeholders with data that comes from that API

The questions are:

1. What is the best way to call 3rd party API from Wordpress?
2. Is there a way to create template pages and then fill them out with data?
3. Are you aware of any plugins that would help?

Additional details:

1. All API endpoint are GET
2. We should be able to add parameters to the API calls.

Comment: 1. The "best way" depends on many factors. But one way is to use WordPress' wp_remote_get function. But obviously you could also fetch the data with JavaScript, Vue, React, etc.
2. Yes, you can create custom page templates and fill them with the returned JSON data
3. Do you want to display the raw JSON data or insert certain parts in HTML elements?

Comment: @Tokant thank you, actually Vue and React are not options here. We could do it via JS but I worry it is going to affect load time and I'd rather do that on the backend
I actually would like to be able to insert those JSON data in HTML elements

Answer (score 1):

In that case the wp_remote_get function is your friend.
Create a page template in WordPress (ressource:
https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/), then retrieve the data from your REST API and insert in the page template:

```
<?php /* Template Name: Example Template */ ?>

<?php 
$url = 'http://example.org/api';
$response = wp_remote_get( esc_url_raw( $url ) );
$api_response = json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response ), true );
print_r($api_response);
?>
```

$api_response will hold an array of data from your JSON.